# Javascript array declaration (possibly mis-using length attribute?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get the innerHTML of red font tags...

```
var fontTags = document.getElementsByTagName('font');
var reds = [];
var j = 0;
var i = 0; // ETA this line
for (i;i<=fontTags.length;i++) { // ETA the 'i<='
  if (fontTags[i].getAttribute('color') == 'RED') {
    reds[j] = fontTags[i].innerHTML;
    j++;
  }
}
```

The javascript console is informing me that "fontTags[i]" is undefined. I've tried no declaration, declaring with 'new Array()'... same thing. Help?

Comment: You are leaking a global `i` and really shouldn't use `<font>` tags at all.

Comment: If `fontTags.length` is larger than `0`,  `fontTags.length` will **always** evaluate to `true`. Hence, at some moment `i` will be (equal) larger than `fontTags.length`. You want to compare it against the current counter, like `i < fontTags.length`.

Comment: isn't your condition always true? and `i` will grow more than the number of elements in the `nodeList`, thus `fontTags[i]` will be undefined.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It's for a Greasemonkey script ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is missing a proper loop-condition.

```
for (i=0;i<fontTags.length;i++) {
    if (fontTags[i].getAttribute('color') == 'RED') {
        reds[j] = fontTags[i].innerHTML;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies. See edit for fixed code. I still see the same error, however.

Comment: it's what sirko wrote, but your condition is still in error. less than; and not less than or equal to.

Comment: Yes, because I'm starting at zero, and the length doesn't... duh. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`for (i=0;i<fontTags.length;i++) {`

check the for loop condition

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for(i=0;i<fontTags.length;i++)
```

instead for (i=0;fontTags.length;i++)